# Push data in unity Player without Requesting

Tags: unity, c#, python, rest, webservice

I have a unity3d Player where I need **some data from the server**. The server code is written in python while on client side is C#.

Now I am searching a way that **server directly post/push data to my unity player**. IMO! it is not possible to push data to unity player without requesting the server using WWW class. My question is can python post data to my client unity player? with something like

```
response = requests.post(client_url, data = request_data, headers = headers)
```

I want to do this because [i want to avoid repetitive calls to server which is not an efficient way.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149466/how-do-i-know-the-data-has-arrived-at-server-without-requesting-every-frame-of-t)

Comment: Generally speaking, a game client doesn't have a `client_url` for your Python server to ping.  It's *possible* to structure your app so that it's essentially a server, but you'll generally run into problems (even at the NAT/Firewall level).  That architecture can also put a lot of the work (managing lists of clients to contact, making calls which may never get answered, etc.) on the server side, which is normally *not* what you want.  Have you looked into the techniques mentioned in the answer of the article you linked?  They're some common ways of making clients request "future" updates.

Comment: Thanks for input. You are right getting client url is not easy as their are NAT also involve. what else should i do

Comment: The answer given in link is not also acceptable (maybe long polling is acceptable). websocket are browser based and unity networking is not feasible as i can't use unity it on server.